# Need a clever way to get orders from all stores while each store is in a different database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

## The setup

I have the following database setup:

- **CentralDB**

  - Table: Stores
  - Table: Users
- Store1DB

  - Table: Orders
- Store2DB

  - Table: Orders
- Store3DB

  - Table: Orders
- Store4DB

  - Table: Orders
- ... etc

CentralDB contains the users, logging and a Stores table with the name of each store database and general information about each store such as address, name, description, image, etc...
All the StoreDB's use the same structure just different data.

It is important to know that the list of stores will shrink and increase in the future.

The main client communicating with this setup is an API REST Service which gets passed a STOREID in the Header of each request telling it which database to connect to. This works flawlessly so far.

## The reasoning

- Whenever we need to do database maintenance on one store, we don't want all other stores to be down.
- Backup management should be per store
- Not having to write the `WHERE storeID=x` every time and for every table
- Performance: each store could run on its own database server if the need arises

## The goal

I need my REST API Service to somehow get all orders from all stores in one query.

Will you help me figure out a way to do this without hardcoding all storedb names? I was thinking about a stored procedure on the CentralDB but I was hoping there would be other solutions. In any case it has to be very efficient.

Comment: Are the Store Databases on the same server as the central database or are we talking about different servers ?

Comment: Dynamic SQL might be rearing it's ugly head on this one...

Comment: @Bartdude For now the databases are on the same server, but I would prefer to keep this an open choice for the future. Tanner: I know :-/ that's why I am hoping for a cleaner solution...

Comment: I would suggest using views or schemas to separate the stores in a single database, and using the standard features (failover, clustering, etc) to ensure high availability

Comment: Do you just need the data from each `Orders` table, or do you a) not store the `StoreID` within that table and b) actually need to identify which store each order is associated with?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Both yes, I need all order data from all stores including the storeid for each order

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to have a list of databases stored in a "system" table in CentralDB.

Then you could create a stored procedure that would read the database names from the table, loop through them with cursor and generate a dynamic SQL that would UNION the results from all the databases. This way you would get a single recordset of results.

However, this database design is IMHO flawed. There is no reason for using multiple databases to store data that belongs to the same "domain". All the reasons that you have mentioned can be solved by using a single database with proper database design. Having multiple databases  will create multiple problems on the long term:

- you will need to change structure of all the DBs when you modify your database model
- you will need to create/drop new databases when new stores are added/removed from your system
- you will need to have items and other entities that are "common" to all the stores duplicated in all the DBs
- what about reporting requirements (e.g. get sales data for stores 1 and 2 together, etc.) - this will require creating complex union queries...
- etc...

On the long term, managing and maintaining this model will be a big pain.

Comment: I was expecting an answer as such. I have considered the issues you mention but I doubt they can *all* be solved by a *proper* database design. I don't see how schemas and views (without a lot of hardcoded names in my entity framework model) can bring solace here. But I am always eager to learn!

Comment: why don't you have everything in single database and using a column (e.g. StoreID) to link data to a specific store? The performance will not be a problem with proper indexing, partitioning, etc. You will need to query the data by filtering on the StoreID column, but this is a minor problem if you compare the alternatives (e.g. using multiple databases with complex unions, etc.).

Comment: I've considered this when I started with this design but consider this: What if a shopkeeper has messed up his product catalog and requires a restore? I'd have to take all stores down and be ready for a lot of scripting while in my current case, it'd just be a simple DB restore.

Comment: I know there's reasons for it and reasons against it. I didn't ask this question to discuss that. If this becomes an ugly thing to do, I might look for a way in the middle and modify some of my database design, it will be a struggle to find one though

Comment: sure, it's your call. i think it comes down to this: what is the probability and time that is needed to do a restore vs. additional time spent on development / maintenance of such (multidatabase) design. i'm quite sure that such model will be a pain on the long-term, because this is simply not good DB design. just my 2c.

Answer (score 2):

I'd maintain a set of views that `UNION ALL` all the data. Every time a store is added or deleted those views must be updated. This can be automated.

The views provide an illusion to the application that there is only one database.

What I would *not* do is have each SQL query or procedure query all the database names and create dynamic SQL. That would entail lots of code duplication and an unnecessary loss of performance. This approach is error prone. Better generate code once in a central place and have all other SQL code reference that generated code.

Comment: I like this approach. With the current design I have a script to create or remove a store (due to the new DB and such). It might just as well update a simple view.